# How to detect multiprocessing.Pipe is full?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipc, python-multiprocessing

**Problem description:** I am doing multiprocessing in Python and using multiprocessing.Pipe() to communicate between processes. I have been searching a lot but still couldn't find a way to detect whether the Pipe is full or not. For example below, the writePipe process keeps putting the number into 2 different Pipes (Odd & Even) and the readPipe process continuously read from these 2 Pipes. However, the speed of read from Odd Pipe is much faster so the Even Pipe will be full. At that moment, the writePipe process will be blocked while the readPipe process still keep waiting to read from Odd Pipe which causes deadlock.

**My question:** Is there any way we can detect the Pipe is full so we can stop putting number into full Pipe while still running and put number into the Pipe which still has spaces?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


def writePipe(sendNumberOdd, sendNumberEven):
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            sendNumberEven.send(i)
        else:
            sendNumberOdd.send(i)
        i += 1

def readPipe(recvNumberOdd, recvNumberEven):
    countEven = 0
    while True:
        countEven += 1
        print(countEven, recvNumberEven.recv())

        countOdd = 0
        while countOdd < 50:
            countOdd += 1
            print (countOdd, recvNumberOdd.recv())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    recvNumberOdd, sendNumberOdd = Pipe(duplex=False)
    recvNumberEven, sendNumberEven = Pipe(duplex=False)

    write = Process(target=writePipe, args=(sendNumberOdd, sendNumberEven))
    read = Process(target=readPipe, args=(recvNumberOdd, recvNumberEven))
    write.start()
    read.start()

    sendNumberOdd.close()
    sendNumberEven.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/select.html#select.select) function from the `select` module to implement a test for whether an output pipe is full.

```
import select
import multiprocessing.connection as mpc


def pipe_full(conn):
    r, w, x = select.select([], [conn], [], 0.0)
    return 0 == len(w)


i, o = mpc.Pipe(duplex=False)

n = 0
while not pipe_full(o):
    o.send(n)
    n += 1

print('{} items fit.'.format(n))
```

Comment: I think `pipe_full` tests whether `select.PIPE_BUF` bytes are writable to the pipe (?).

Comment: @user66081: yes, according to the documentation, that is the definition of "full" in the case of pipes:https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/select.html#select.PIPE_BUF

Answer (score 0):

> **Proposal UNTESTED**
>
> ```
> class Connection(multiprocessing.Connection):
>     def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
>         self.__maxsize = maxsize
>         self.size = 0
>         self.__lock = multiprocessing.Lock
>
>     def send(self, obj):
>         with self.__lock:
>             self.size += sizeof(obj)
>         super().send(obj)
>
>     def recv(self):
>         _recv = super().recv()
>         with self.__lock:
>             self.size -= sizeof(_recv)
>         return _recv
>
>     def full(self):
>         if self.__maxsize > 0:
>             return self.size >= self.__maxsize
>         return None
>
> def Pipe(maxsize=0, duplex=True):
>     return Connection(maxsize), Connection(maxsize)
> ```

---

Implement a `poll()` to check if any Data to be ready.

> Python » Documentation: [poll([timeout])](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Connection)
>
> ```
> Return whether there is any data available to be read.
> ```

For example:

```
if recvNumberEven.poll():
    countEven += 1
    print(countEven, recvNumberEven.recv())
```

Alternative use `wait(...)` for both

> [multiprocessing.connection.wait(object_list, timeout=None)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.wait)
>
> ```
> Wait till an object in object_list is ready.  
> Returns the list of those objects in object_list which are ready.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think you are misunderstanding my problem. What I need is a way to detect whether the Pipe is full to stop sending more data into the pipe from the writePipe process to prevent the deadlock. Meanwhile, the poll() can only be used to know if there is any data in Pipe to read so it could not help in this situation. I need something similar to Queue.put(block=False) or Queue.put_nowait which raises the queue.Full exception so that I can handle when the Pipe is full.

Comment: @Le Quoc Khanh: There is no _**Pipe is full**_ Condition, your only Solution is to prevent the `Consumer` Process to _**waif forever**_ .

Comment: Thank you again but as my understanding, multiprocessing.Queue is built on top of Pipe and it has some mechanism to detect and raise queue.Full exception when Queue is full. I have tried to read the source code of queues.py in multiprocessing library and noticed that it used some kind of Boundedsemaphore to detect but I still dont understand the logic. Do you have any clue about that?

Comment: `Queue`handle this using a Size Counter, Condition _**FULL**_ is `True` if Size Counter equal Data in Buffer. But why reinvent the wheel, why does `Queue` not fit your needs?

Comment: Because the performance of Queue is really slow (~ 3 time slower than Pipe) due to the fact that Queue is implemented with some mechanism for multi-producer and multi-consumer safe which I don't need (I only use single-producer, single-consumer IPC in half-duplex). Since I have to process a lot of data in real-time, I have to choose using Pipe rather than Queue. Could you please explain in more detail how Queue works to detect if it is full and how I can apply a similar method for Pipe. I really appreciate that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @LeQuocKhanh: Updated my Answer